# How to exclude row that is matched 100% in mysql full text search?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, full-text-search, where-clause

I have a table and data

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    FULLTEXT (title)
) Engine=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO articles (title) VALUES
    ('PostgreSQL Tutorial'),
    ('Tricks MySQL Well'),
    ('MySQL'),
    ('1001 MySQL Tricks'),
    ('MySQL vs. YourSQL'),
    ('MySQL Security');
```

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
WHERE 
MATCH (title)
  AGAINST ('+MySQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get this result as expected

```
id  title
2   Tricks MySQL Well
3   MySQL
4   1001 MySQL Tricks
5   MySQL vs. YourSQL
6   MySQL Security
```

My question is how to exclude row with value "MySQL"?

Need an efficient solution.

Here is fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/268411/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just adding another condition to the `where` clause?

```
WHERE 
    MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+MySQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND title <> 'MySQL'
```

Comment: Do `AND title <> 'MySQL'` also use full text index?